# Access web service on azure VM

Tags: azure, curl, ip, endpoint

I have a jersey/grizzly web service running on an Azure VM with Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS. I can access the web service from within the machine with curl, but from outside the machine the request just times out.

That is, I can do this curl line:

```
curl -X POST http://example.cloudapp.net:80/resource/path --data "text=´Mario"
```

and get a response from within the shell of the VM, but not from my windows console, or another VM in the same Azure datacenter.

I start the Grizzly web server on port 9998 in my `Main.java`:

```
public class Main {

    public static final URI BASE_URI = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://0.0.0.0/").port(9998).build();

    protected static SelectorThread startServer() throws IOException {
        final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "mypackage");
        SelectorThread threadSelector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(BASE_URI, initParams);     
        return threadSelector;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SelectorThread threadSelector = startServer();
        System.in.read();
        threadSelector.stopEndpoint();
    }    
}
```

And I can see it listening with `netstat -a`:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:9998                  *:*                     LISTEN
```

I have set up an Azure endpoint so that I can access the webservice on the VM, making the translation between the inner port 9998 and the outer port 80.

[image: Azure endpoint]

There are no ACL rules on the endpoint, so the [default](http://www.cloudcomputingadmin.com/articles-tutorials/windows-azure/windows-azure-virtual-machine-endpoints-explained.html) is to let everything through.

My iptables in the VM is set to let everything through:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
```

My theory is that the problem is outside the virtual machine, but I don't know where to begin. Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this or how to proceed with the troubleshooting? Please ask, if there is anything else you need. One thing that might help is if I could get the access attempt logs for the Azure endpoints, but I don't know how to get them.